# "Looks Good" instead of "Looks OK" still remaining

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

"Looks Good" was recently changed to "Looks OK" because posts don't have to be "good", just not "delete worthy".

So the button changed: [image: Looks OK]… but the information after you've reviewed or it's been completed is still the same:

> [image: Looks Good]

Can it be changed to "Looks OK"?

Comment: This questions Looks OK.

Comment: MSE: [Low quality review records say “Looks Good” instead of “Looks OK”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234986/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I decided that your request for this change *Looks OK* and so I changed the wording. It'll be live in the next prod build (> rev `2014.7.9.2357`).