# Low quality queue - action for answers hard to understand

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

What action should I take when the answer is so badly written it's hard to understand what the AP is trying to tell?

It certainly shouldn't be a comment, the comment should be human-readable as well. It's not 'thank you' or 'link only', and it's hard to tell what it actually is.

Maybe it was an attempt to ask a new question, but as a question it would be closed as 'unclear what you are asking'? Suggesting to post that as a question would not be very appropriate.

There's no delete reason 'unclear what you are answering'.

Should I just delete with 'no comment needed'?

Comment: @MichaelT - I don't think its a duplicate. This question appears to ask about amorphic substance. The cited dup seems to ask more of style than substance. Forgive me if I am reading things too narrowly (but I don't like to make leaps).  
Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt's question reminds me of [Saturday Night Live's Pat](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS_gQd8UB-hKhNUiNJmkGdx8jFNMr_Riu).

Comment: @jww my suggestion of duplication was based on that when reading this answer I had the strong urge to copy a significant portion of my answer in the other question here. I suspect other people would give answers much like Andrew's in that other question.  I'm strongly of the opinion that activist delete voters are a good thing, especially when the community is having difficulty fighting the crap that exists.  If one finds something that is low quality and not able to be fixed - delete it.  And thats what I said in my other answer... thus, my flagging this as a dup.

Comment: I find that "unclear what you're answering" is usually covered by NAA, but you can't flag from the LQP queue, so recommending deletion is probably your best bet.

Comment: @AstroCB I've had [difficulty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined) with NAA flags in the past. Some mods have taken the stance that if there is an *attempt* to answer the question, the NAA flag is inappropriate in that situation and thus declined.

Comment: @MichaelT True, but that was my default action up until a couple of months ago when that stance changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>disclaimer: I believe you should review in a way that reflects what you want on the site.  This does not always match other guidance given elsewhere. I'm also not a 20k (much less a 2k) member on SO, so this is heavily influenced by how I act on Programmers.SE.</sup>

The review queue for Low Quality Posts has a caption that reads:

> ### Low Quality Posts
>
> Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts

This is the criteria and actions that you have for the LQP review.

In this review queue you have four options:

> - **Looks OK** if nothing is wrong with this answer
> - **Edit** if you can fix all the problems with this answer
> - **Recommend Deletion** to recommend that this answer be deleted
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

As you have noted, the option of "Looks OK" is improper for such a question.  It doesn't look ok and you are having difficulty reading it and it is very poorly written.  This is part of the 'Identify' part of the review queue description.

If you are able to improve it and fix *all* the problems with the answer, by all means, edit it.  A good answer is better than no answer.  And if you can make this into a good answer, that is the best possible outcome.  This is the 'Improve' part of the review queue description.

However, once again note that you are having difficulty with coming to grips with that. Such a change would be drastic to the point of it would likely be mostly your words.  This is sometimes ok for questions (doing an Attwoodian transformation), but answers have much less mandate to do so.  If you find yourself looking at a question and saying "I really could completely rewrite that into a much better answer", you should probably do that... but as a separate answer.

This brings us to the third part of the Low Quality Post answer review - "Delete".  If its not a good answer, if it doesn't reflect the type of material you would expect to see on Stack Overflow (or for a higher threshold - that you would *want* to see on Stack Overflow), delete it (or recommend doing so if you have less than 20k rep).

While I admit that this is the controversial part, and also is a [sisyphean task](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sisyphean+task) in the face of the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), it is an option there.  Know that someone else coming in would see the un-understandable answer and go "huh?" just as you are.  It also shows Stack Overflow in a poor light - that such is the quality of the material that is accepted and maybe, the quality of the material that is becoming *expected*.

If you don't want to make any of these decisions, skip it.  Thats an option and one that is a good one for situations where you really don't know.  There are other reviewers who are willing to take up the borderline ones and may be able to decipher the answer sufficiently to improve it, or press delete it with more conviction.  There is rarely a lack of low quality reviewers.

As I said in my disclaimer at the start - review for how you want the site to be and how you want to be for the next person finding the answer.

Comment: Looks OK, not good now.

Comment: @bjb568 Thank you - I didn't realize there was a wording change from when I last wrote an answer about this.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259879/839601