# LQP queue unusually full: is VLQ/NAA being misused?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

[image: tubes clogging]

This is up from about a week ago where it was around 20 posts.

The issue is: much of the stuff in the queue should not be in there. (Questions that should be closed as 'unclear' or 'minimal example', answers that should be downvoted but not deleted...)

If the LQ queue just becomes another queue for close votes then it is much less useful. It's mainly useful to identify gibberish and dispose of it **quickly**. As soon as there are 100 posts in there, I don't have time to actually go through it.

Maybe this is not a trend, just a blip, but this is an unusually large amount of LQ flags.

Note that the misuse I've perceived here is both by flaggers as well as reviewers. Just for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/27100532 (now deleted):

[image: users redacted]

While I might feel personally satisfied when an answer I thought to myself was crap gets deleted, from what I have read, I really don't think this should have entered the queue. I basically thought this queue existed so we could delete gibberish and offensive links. (Both of which I have seen in the queue.)

I *thought* that the answer pictured should just get downvoted a lot, not deleted by *us*. Same thing with answers that *contain a link* but are not *just a link*. (Though we have been over the link-only thing many, many times.)

Also, there have been quite a few questions on meta lately about audits and such involving this queue so there appears to be some confusion surrounding its purpose. Also, I think the queue may be itself confused about its own purpose.

- **Does something need to be done about this?**
- **What can be done about this?**

At the very least, I think question closing should really, really not be a part of the LQ queue workflow. We already have a queue for that.

If this is indeed a trend, some other solutions I can think of are:

- The review option 'Looks OK' prompts for a reason, similar to rejecting an edit, which the flagger receives.
- Splitting the queue to two or more queues so these different purposes don't interfere with each other.

Comment: It may also be that today was Thanksgiving in the United States and not as many people visited. The queue has dropped to zero repeatedly through out the week.

Comment: @Andy That's true, also the queue has dropped since I posted this (now only 11 posts). Though lately when I check the queues it is around 20 posts which is already more than it used to be.

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271840/839601): "The review queue for Low Quality Posts has a caption...  _Identify, then improve or delete low-quality posts_

This is the criteria and actions that you have for the LQP review..."

Comment: And it was definitely 0 on Wednesday when I handled it. The queue should be back to 0 by next week for sure.

Comment: I have always found it strange that I use close votes in the LQ queue. My impression is that the number of LQ questions in the queue is actually lower since a few days compared to before. I don't have number or a hard proof, though.

Comment: One of the reasons this might be higher is that "very low quality" flags are now delayed in being presented to moderators. They don't appear in our flag queue until being available to the community for at least an hour. At least, that's what the community team was experimenting with starting this last week.

Comment: *"As soon as there are 100 posts in there, I don't have time to actually go through it"* - I don't understand this statement. Nobody is forcing you to go through all of it. Also, you can only do 20 reviews a day, So if you're not sure about something, **skip** it, If you're sure about something, then **take action**. Keep in mind that you only get to do 20 reviews. So the fact that there are 100, 200, or 500 posts in there should not be affecting your decisions.

Comment: @TJ Okay, so my question could read that "I *can't* go through it". That doesn't really change how the queue got larger.

Comment: Note that there are certain times certain scripts run that can push large numbers of posts into the queue.  Things like (a hypothetical script) "on the 28th of the month, have the system automatically flag all posts that are posted in the last 60 days with a quality score of less than N that have a vote score of 0 or lower that haven't already been flagged by this process".  The key point here being there are automatic flagging scripts too (not just people), and on a site as large as SO, those can cause some backlog in the queue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not going to address everything in your question. I'll just say I'm not seeing a problem with the LQ queue, and move on to specific issues...

> I basically thought this queue existed so we could delete gibberish and offensive links.

Fundamental mistake here. Flags that are raised for offensive posts (which I guess "offensive links" are) are handled by moderators, not by the queue. Gibberish does end up in that queue but also:

1. Things that users posted as answers but that are not actually answers: "Thanks to @foo for the answer.", "Did someone find a solution?...", "I have a related question...", "I would comment but I can't because...." These are not "gibberish" since they are understandable and they do not necessarily contain links so they do not fall under the "offensive links" category.
2. Link only answers, when the link is not an "offensive link".

The specific example you gave is an answer that merely restates what was already established in the question. You can argue that it was a genuine *attempt* at answering the question, just a bad attempt, and thus it should not have been flagged. Irrespective of this, however, **this answer should still be deleted.** Why?

We do delete answers that repeat what an earlier has already provided if the earlier answer is substantially earlier. To do this, you raise a custom flag and explain that the newer answer is just repeating what the earlier one already established, and you point out the time difference. A moderator will evaluate and, if you are right, will delete the newer answer. Since we do this when an answer repeats another answer, then we should also do this when an answer merely repeats what is established in the question. So **even if** we accept that raising a flag on that answer and deleting it in the queue was not the appropriate path to deletion, it remains that the answer should be deleted.

Comment: Well your 1. I know about (falls under NAA) and I guess my difficulty is lately I've felt like I've had to wade through other stuff to get to these reviews. WRT deletion, is there a meta thread you are immediately aware of? I was pretty sure I've seen statements to the opposite. But anyhow I gave you an upvote because this is helpful.

Comment: Regarding deletion, I'm starting form the well established practice that we delete duplicate answers and stating that if we do that, then we should also delete answers that merely restate what the question has already established. I know of posts regarding the former but not the latter. There's this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274826/1906307). See also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/241526) which is essentially a request by a SO moderator to streamline requests for deletion of duplicate answers.

Comment: I did find [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270004/2891664) (which contains additional links), though they are generally discussing a different type of answer than I've pictured in the question.

Answer (score 4):

This might be low quality:

[image]

As it shows a lack of research effort, be localized and is unlikely to help future readers / googlers who actually googles, however as you mentioned it is not flag-worthy:

[To flag or not to flag question that don't show own effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223480/266094)

**However**, `N/3 - N/2` of the questions I see in the queue are actually unanswerable. If the question doesn't seem low quality, you should vote to leave it as is:

[image]

And if you prefer, go back to the review task, visit and downvote the original question. That's what I do at least, as same as for answers. It is true that *some* reviewers have no problem with voting for `(recommending) deletion` with everything, but I consider these edge cases. The queue also comes with candidates for "Not An Answer" (should had been anything out of the answer box).

So I just went reviewing. Aside from two answers which attempted to answer the question, here are the rest of the items in the queue I managed to come upon (Spoiler alert: I voted for "recommend deletion" for all of them):

[image]

I too agree that sloppy reviewers are present. That's why I like the audit system.
While mistakes are made, I do believe that they are edge cases.

```
Does something need to be done about this?
What can be done about this?
```

Nothing. I don't see a problem, since the queue is now empty.

[image]

Comment: WRT to the quantity of posts, I did the same, using all 20 of my reviews. Now, an hour later, there are 45 posts in the queue again. The size of the queue is still manageable. What I noticed is that it got larger. (Though of course Brad Larson's comment indicates this may be due to an internal adjustment.)